# How to remove video button while in Flutter Jitsi Meet call screen?

Tags: flutter, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am using Jitsi Meet Flutter Library in my app and I want to remove video option while in the calling screen(To make it look like its just a voice call). So is there any feasible way or tactic to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No theres no such way to do what you want if you are using default server but if you are using your own server then you can customize it. Or else if you want to do it with default server then you have to recompile the react native SDK again your self according to your needs.

Suggestion: better use agora SDK for voice calling and jitsi for video calling. As agora provides support and customizations for separately voice and video call.

Comment: Hope this helps you...if you have still any doubt then comment here or if it helped you then please upvote and mark the answer correct.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Actually we using our own server for jitsi. So how can we remove video option while performing a voice call, I mean what changes need to be done in our server file of jitsi?
Let me know if you have any idea for it.

Comment: You better ask in the GitHub repository of the jitsi meet plugin or official jitsi SDK repo as they will be able to tell in detail...I know but telling here would be difficult...but I can tell you that much you need to change configuration.js and change ui according to your need. If I managed to help you out then please upvote and mark the answer correct!

Comment: Sure buddy. Thanks for guiding us. Will let you know what happens. Kudos !!!

Comment: were you able to remove video option in flutter plugin?

Comment: Nope, but maybe you can in your own server...try it... if u succeed tell us